# Running Jasmine through Visual Studio 2017 (with ReSharper)

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, jasmine, resharper

I am attempting to run Jasmine automation against Angular2/Typescript in Visual Studio 2017.  The Test Runner fires off just fine but all tests are ignored saying the task skipped on a Timeout.  This is instantaneous, no way it hit a timeout.  I have a `<reference path="......">` pointing at the Typings index.d.ts without luck.  Does anyone have any experience here?

Comment: Did you find a resolution for this?